# STDOUT redirected to variable not catching pipe output

Tags: perl

I want to temporarily redirect stdout to an in memory variable. Prints are correctly redirected to my variable but not the output of a pipe (bc in my example). What is going on?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $stdout_sink;
open(my $orig_stdout, ">&STDOUT") || die $!;
close STDOUT;
open(STDOUT, ">", \$stdout_sink) || die $!;

# produce some output in different ways
print "before bc\n"; # ok
open my $fh, "| bc";
print $fh "2+2\n";   # not ok
close $fh;

close STDOUT;  
open(STDOUT, ">&", $orig_stdout) || die $!;
print "$stdout_sink";
```

Actual ouput will be:

```
before bc
```

Expected output:

```
before bc
4
```

Comment: `bc` is forked and run as a separate process with an independent STDOUT. You need to run it using something like [`IPC::Run3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) to capture the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ... not possible.

Standard output of piped opens and `system` calls are written to file descriptor 1. Normally, Perl's `STDOUT` file handle is associated with file descriptor 1, but that can be manipulated.

In this example, the `system` calls writes to `STDOUT` filehandle, which writes to the file `foo`.

```
close STDOUT;             # closes file descriptor 1
open STDOUT, '>', 'foo';  # reopens STDOUT as file descriptor 1
system("echo bar");
close STDOUT;
print STDERR "foo: ",`cat foo`;
# result:  "foo: bar"
```

But in this example, the `system` calls writes to the `BAZ` filehandle.

```
close STDOUT;             # closes file descriptor 1
open BAZ, '>', 'baz';     # attaches fd 1 to handle BAZ
open STDOUT, '>', 'foo';  # opens new file descriptor, maybe fd 3
system("echo bar");
close STDOUT;
print STDERR "foo: ",`cat foo`;
print STDERR "baz: ",`cat baz`;
# result:  "foo: baz: bar"
```

An in-memory filehandle is not a real filehandle. If you call `fileno` on it, you will (generally, may be OS dependent) get a negative number.

```
open STDOUT, '>', \$scalar;
print STDERR fileno(STDOUT);     #   -1
```

Piped opens and system calls will not be able to write to this filehandle.

You will need a more complicated workaround, like writing the piped open output to a file, and then copying that file into the in-memory variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have a detailed explanation in [mob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045319/4653379) of why you cannot redirect a child's `STDOUT` to a variable, which isn't really a filehandle.

Instead, you can use a module for running external programs, that can redirect standard streams to variables. Then you can combine strings with redirected output as you wish.

An example with [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use IPC::Run3;

open my $fh, ">", \my $so_1;     
my $old = select $fh;         # make $fh the default for output,
say "To select-ed default";   # so prints end up in $so_1

run3 ["ls", "-l", "./"], undef, \my $so_2;   # output goes to $so_2

select $old;                  # restore STDOUT as default for output
print $so_1, $so_2;
```

Here I used [select](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to manipulate where prints go by default (without a filehandle specified).

Note that the example redirects `run3` to a different variable (`$so_2`) than the one used for a previous redirect.  If you'd rather append to the same variable specify this in [`%options`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#%5C%options)

```
run3 ["ls", "-l", "./"], undef, \$so_1, { append_stdout => 1 };
```

and remove `$so_2` from the printing statement.

The module uses temporary files for this redirection, as mob also indicated in the answer.

Some other options are [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm) that can redirect output from nearly any code, with a simple and clean interface, and the very powerfull, rounded, and more complex [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.96/lib/IPC/Run.pm).