# does Perl's Capture::Tiny::capture() avoid disk io required when using system()?

Tags: perl, io

When calling an external program from a Perl script, does Capture::Tiny avoid disk io required when using system()? I get essentially the same performance when using either. A colleague is using my code and told me that it was hammering his disks. I (perhaps) don't have this problem when running on my local machine and writing to local disks.

I was previously doing this:

```
open($fhStdin, ">stdin.txt");
print $fhStdin "some text\n";
close($fhStdin);
system("cmd < stdin.txt 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt"); 
# open and read stdout.txt
# open and read stderr.txt
```

And changed to this:

```
($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
    open($fhStdin, '| cmd');
    print $fhStdin "some text\n";
    close($fhStdin);
};
```

But NYTProf tells me that they take essentially the same amount of time to run (but NYTProf removes disk io overheads from subroutine times). So I wondered if capture() is writing to temporary files under the hood? (I tried reading the Tiny.pm source code but am ashamed to say I couldn't tell from that.)

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: In general your Capture::Tiny implementation does less IO. It's not reading and writing to the disk. Weird.

Comment: Slight typo... should have been 'system("cmd < stdin.txt 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt")', sorry.

Comment: You can [edit] your question with the [edit] link below the question, or use this [edit] link. ;)

Comment: The two code snippets behave differently. In the first case you are letting the shell manage input to `cmd` from a file which you first wrote, in the second case you are feeding it input ... how? Can you show how `# write cmd input to $fh` goes (in a nutshell)? As it stands I don't see why it would incur _more_ disk access.

Comment: @zdim In the first case I print the text expected by the external program to a file, and then let the shell pass this to cmd's stdin (as you said). In the second case I open a pipe to cmd and thereby print the same text directly to cmd's stdin. (i.e. avoiding the need for my script to write an intermediary file.) Sorry if this wasn't clear, I've edited my post to (hopefully) improve this.

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking that the nature of what is done may matter, but in fact `capture` just does use files, plain and simple. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [Capture::Tiny::capture](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#capture)  states that files are indeed used

> Captures are normally done to an anonymous temporary filehandle.

This can be seen in the source for the [_capture_tee](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L303) sub, used as a generic routine for all methods. About half-way through this sub we find a [call to `File::Temp->new`](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L360) happening, unless named files are to be used (see below).  The rest of processing can be traced with some care.<sup>†</sup>

The docs proceed to offer a way to monitor all this via named files instead

> To capture via a named file (e.g. to externally monitor a long-running capture), provide custom filehandles as a trailing list of option pairs:

> ```
> my $out_fh = IO::File->new("out.txt", "w+");
> ```

```
my $err_fh = IO::File->new("out.txt", "w+");
capture { ... } stdout => $out_fh, stderr => $err_fh;
```

> The filehandles must be read/write and seekable. Modifying the files or filehandles during a capture operation will give unpredictable results. Existing IO layers on them may be changed by the capture.

(If this is done then the call to `File::Temp` doesn't go, as mentioned above. See source.)

If this disk activity is a problem you can use piped [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to read `cmd`'s output
(write its input to a file first), or use [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) (backticks).  But then you'd have to merge or redirect `STDERR` and go through more hoops to check and handle error.

Another option is to use [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm). While it also [uses files](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#HOW_IT_WORKS) it offers far more options which may be leveraged to lessen the disk I/O, or perhaps avoid disk altogether. (The idea to invoke with a filehandle *opened to a scalar* (in-memory) doesn't work since this isn't a real filehandle.<sup>‡</sup> )

The "nuclear" option is the more complex [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etoddr/IPC-Run-0.97/lib/IPC/Run.pm) which can take output without using disk.

---

<sup>†</sup> A crude sketch

The "dispatch" of all methods to `_capture_tee` is done [in the beginning](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L36), where a set of flags is `unshift`ed to `@_` before `goto &func` takes it away, to distinguish methods. For `capture` this is `1,1,0,0`, what sets up variables `$do_stdout` and `$do_stderr` in `_capture_tee`. These are then used to set up the [`%do` hash](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L306), which keys are [iterated over to set up `$stash`](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L360).

If extra arguments were passed to `capture` (for named files) then [`$stash->{capture}` is set](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L309), otherwise a `File::Temp` object is assigned.
The `$stash` is later [passed to `_open_std`](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm#L370) where the redirection happens.

A lot more is happening, but mostly related to manipulation of localized globs and layers.

---

<sup>‡</sup>    The most usual invocation writes to scalar(s)

```
run3 \@cmd, \my $in, \my $out, \my $err;
```

but this uses files, as explained in docs under [How it works](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#HOW_IT_WORKS).

An attempt to trick it into not using files, by writing to a filehandle which is opened to a scalar

```
my @cmd = qw(ls -l .);
open my $fh, '>', \my $cmd_out;  # not a real filehandle ...
run3 \@cmd, \undef, $fh;         # ... so this won't work
```

aborts with

```
run3(): Invalid argument redirecting STDOUT at ...
```

This is because an `open` to a scalar doesn't set up a real filehandle. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045319/4653379).

If the filehandle is opened to a file this works as intended, writing to that file.  This may well result in a more efficient disk I/O operation, compared with what `Capture::Tiny` does.

Comment: Shouldn't that `run3` command with output to a scalar be using a reference to a scalar: `run3 \@cmd, \undef, \my $cmd_out`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @HåkonHægland right, but that invocation uses files (it explains it at the link).  I thought that it can perhaps be tricked -- write to a filehandle ("_if the redirector already specifies a filehandle it just uses that_") but open it to a scalar ... but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Edited that footnote, hopefully my attempt is clearer now. Thank you

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply, with possible alternative methods. I'd seen the use of File::Temp (which I was also using in my version that used system()) but I couldn't tell if it was used for all streams or something else.

Comment: @zdim Yes, I think I understand the issue now. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Recalled why this "idea" fails and updated.

Comment: @Matthew  Glad that it helps. I've updated the footnote, with a reason why one can't write to an in-memory "filehandle" (which isn't).