# With perl open, how can I capture bash STDOUT & STDERR without printing to disk?

Tags: bash, perl, system, stderr, filehandle

The perl script below invokes unix `find` using
the `open` command.

STDOUT goes into the CMD filehandle and
STDERR, if any, goes into a temporary file on disk.

STDERR will result if the user makes a mistake on the command  line.
But even if the user makes a mistake, it is still possible that STDOUT could contain useful data, as in my example below.

Thus we want two separate variables in the perl script, holding
respectively STDOUT and STDERR from the unix command.

In the current script, STDERR is only obtained by first printing
it to a file on disk and subsequently reading the file.

Is there a way to capture both STDOUT and STDERR in separate variables without the intermediate step of printing STDERR to a physical file on disk? Can it somehow be printed directly to a perl filehandle or a perl variable?

I am aware that one can use `File::Find` in perl instead of an explicit system call. But `open` can be applied to other unix commands, so an answer to the current question could be applied to any number of unix commands.

```
> cat z.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my$work={};
$work->{tmpfile}='./z';
$work->{command}=join(' ',
    'find -s ',
    @ARGV,
    '2>',
    $work->{tmpfile},
);

open CMD, '-|', $work->{command} or die $work->{command},' cannot open';
$work->{return}{open}=$?;
my@result;
while(<CMD>)
{
    chomp;
    push@result,$_;
}
close CMD;
$work->{return}{close}=$?;
if(-s $work->{tmpfile})
{
    open IN,'<',$work->{tmpfile} or die 'cannot read ',$work->{tmpfile},;
    local$/=undef;
    $work->{stderr}=<IN>;
    close IN;
}
print Dumper $work;
print Dumper \@result;
> ./z.pl . piggy
$VAR1 = {
          'command' => 'find -s  . piggy 2> ./z',
          'return' => {
                        'close' => 256,
                        'open' => 0
                      },
          'stderr' => 'find: piggy: No such file or directory
',
          'tmpfile' => './z'
        };
$VAR1 = [
          '.',
          './.z.pl.swp',
          './body',
          './body~',
          './snap',
          './title',
          './z',
          './z.pl',
          './z.pl~'
        ];
>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but **don't** `join` the array of arguments when you `open`. Supply the array to `open`. Much safer!

Comment: You want Capture::Tiny.

Comment: You want either IPC::Open3 (comes with Perl) or IPC::Run or Capture::Tiny.

Comment: @TedLyngmo How is it safer? When I break the command into an array, it refuses to run ````find: 2: unknown primary or operator
$VAR1 = {
          'command' => [
                         'find',
                         '-s',
                         '.',
                         '-maxdepth',
                         '1',
                         '2',
                         '>',
                         './z'
                       ],
<etc>
        };
$VAR1 = [];````

Comment: @JacobWegelin It's safer because when you pass a single string it evaluates it as a shell command making it vulnerable to quoting problems and shell exploits. Using an array passes the arguments directly to the command with no shell interpretation. Your command does not work because you need the shell for redirection via `2>`

Comment: It's safer because you don't have the shell between your perl script and the command you're executing.  The shell can do terrible things depending on what arguments the user has supplied in `@ARGV`. Running without the shell in between also means that `2> $work->{tmpfile}` won't work (since that's a shell feature you are using). You need to redirect it yourself.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you. So  for instance: `open CMD, '-|', 'find', '-s', '.', or die 'cannot open';` How then do I redirect it myself?

Comment: Re suggestion to use IPC::Open3, That's not a good idea. It would also require using IO::Select or similar to avoid race conditions, resulting in a rather complex solution.

Answer (score 3):

IPC::Run makes this easy.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my @cmd = ( "find", "-s", ".", "piggy" );

run \@cmd, ">", \my $stdout, "2>", \my $stderr;

my $status = $?;
```

The child inherits STDIN in the above program. You could use the following if that's undesirable:

```perl
run \@cmd, "/dev/null", \my $stdout, \my $stderr;
```

---

But if you're interested in learning the system calls involved, read on.

1. Create three pipes.
2. If this fails,

   1. Abort.
3. Fork.
4. If this fails,

   1. Abort.
5. In the child,

   1. Close the read end of the first pipe.
   2. Close the read end of the second pipe.
   3. Close the read end of the third pipe.
   4. Set the first's pipe's close-on-exec flag.
   5. Open `/dev/null`.
   6. If this fails,

      1. Write an error message to the first pipe.
      2. Call `_exit( 255 )`. (The exit code doesn't matter.)
   7. Use `dup2` to copy the handle to `/dev/null` onto fd 0.
   8. If this fails,

      1. Write an error message to the first pipe.
      2. Call `_exit( 255 )`. (The exit code doesn't matter.)
   9. Close the handle to `/dev/null`.
   10. Use `dup2` to copy the write end the second pipe onto fd 1.
   11. If this fails,

       1. Write an error message to the first pipe.
       2. Call `_exit( 255 )`. (The exit code doesn't matter.)
   12. Close the write end of the second pipe.
   13. Use `dup2` to copy the write end the second pipe onto fd 2.
   14. If this fails,

       1. Write an error message to the first pipe.
       2. Call `_exit( 255 )`. (The exit code doesn't matter.)
   15. Close the write end of the third pipe.
   16. `exec` the program.
   17. If this fails (i.e. if we get here),

       1. Write an error message to the first pipe.
       2. Call `_exit( 255 )`. (The exit code doesn't matter.)
6. Close the write end of the first pipe.
7. Close the write end of the second pipe.
8. Close the write end of the third pipe.
9. Create variable `$error_msg`.
10. Loop,

    1. Read from the first pipe.
    2. If EOF reached,

       1. Exit the loop.
    3. Append what was read to `$error_msg`.
11. If `$error_msg` is defined,

    1. There was an error launching the child. `$error_msg` contains the reason.
    2. Abort.
12. Close the first pipe.
13. Create a `select` bitfield for second and third pipe.
14. Create two variables initialized to empty strings. Each will store data received from one of the two remaining pipes.
15. While the bitfield still has bits set,

    1. Use `select` to wait for data.
    2. For each ready handle,

       1. Use `sysread` to read from the ready handle.
       2. If this fails, (i.e. if `sysread` returned -1),

          1. This shouldn't happen.
          2. Clear the appropriate bit in the bitfield.
       3. If EOF (i.e. if `sysread` returned zero),

          1. Clear the appropriate bit in the bitfield.
       4. Else,

          1. Append the data read to appropriate variable.
16. Close the second pipe.
17. Close the third pipe.
18. Use `waitpid` to wait for the child to exit.

IPC::Open3's `open3` can handle steps 1 to 12 for you.

IO::Select can simplify steps 13 to 15 for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the simple [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

#my @cmd = ('find', '-s', @ARGV);
my @cmd = ( 'ls', '-l', (@ARGV ? shift : '.') );    

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
  system( @cmd );
};

say $stdout          if $stdout;
say "Error: $stderr" if $stderr;
say "exit: $exit"    if $exit;
```

One can run any Perl code inside the block, not only external commands via `system`.  So with this there is no need for shell redirections (can drop that `2> filename` from the command).

This does use files internally, what can also be managed explicitly (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49551601/4653379) in detail, for instance). But I thought the question is about avoiding the need to deal with files in code.

Please be careful with passing user input as arguments to commands.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `IPC::Run` like [ikegami suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75749600/7582247). I just wanted to answer this part of the question OP asked:

> How then do I redirect it myself?

You use `open` to duplicate the file descriptors. Note that this still writes to a separate file and only answers the redirection part.

```perl
sub run {
    my $output = shift; # a file to redirect STDERR to

    print "Running: ('" . join("', '", @_) . "') 2> $output\n";

    # dup STDERR so that we can restore it later
    open(my $err, '>&', \*STDERR) or die "Can't dup stderr: $!";

    # reopen STDERR to output to the supplied file
    open(STDERR, '>', $output) or die "Can't redirect stderr: $!";

    # "open" your command
    open(my $cmd, '-|', @_) or die "Can't exec $_[0]: $!";
    while(<$cmd>) {
        print $_;
    }
    close($cmd);

    # restore STDERR
    open(STDERR, '>&', $err) or die "Can't restore stderr: $!";
    close($err);
}

my @cmd = ('find', '-s', '.', '-maxdepth', '1', '2');

run './z', @cmd;
```

Output on `STDOUT`:

```
Running: ('find', '-s', '.', '-maxdepth', '1', '2') 2> ./z
```

My `find` doesn't know `-s` so output on `STDERR` (and therefore the content of `./z`) became:

```
find: unknown predicate `-s'
```

Comment: The OP asks how to avoid using a temp file, yet your solution uses a temp file...

Comment: @ikegami Yes, it only answered one particular part. I updated the answer to make that even clearer.