# Perl: How to pass IPC::Open3 redirected STDOUT/STDERR fhs

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to capture the output my **perl** code generates both from print and similar statements and external commands.

Due to design constraints I can't use solutions like Capture::Tiny. I need to forward the output to the buffer variable as soon as it is generated and I need to be able to differentiate between **STDOUT** and **STDERR**. Ideally a solution for external commands would essentially work just like system apart from being able to capture **STDOUT** and **STDERR** instead of printing them.

My code is supposed to:

1. Save the old **STDOUT**/**STDERR** file handles.
2. Create a new ones for both **STDERR** and **STDOUT**.
3. Redirect all the output to this place.
4. Print a couple of things.
5. Restore the old filehandles.
6. Do something with the captured output, e.g. print it.

However I'm unable to capture the output generated from external commands. I can't do it with `IPC::Run3` nor with `IPC::Open3`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CSDAL
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Open3;
#use IPC::Run3;

# Save old filehandles
open(my $oldout, ">&STDOUT") or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";
open(my $olderr, ">&STDERR") or die "Can't dup STDERR: $!";

my $buffer = "";

close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);

open(STDOUT, '>', \$buffer) or die "Can't redirect STDOUT: $!";
*STDERR = *STDOUT; # In this example STDOUT and STDERR are printed to the same buffer.

print "1: Test\n";
#run3 ["date"], undef, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR; # This doesn't work as expected
my $pid = open3("<&STDIN", ">&STDOUT", ">&STDERR", "date");
waitpid($pid,0); # Nor does this.

print STDERR "2: Test\n";

open(STDOUT, ">&", $oldout) or die "Can't dup \$oldout: $!";
open(STDERR, ">&", $olderr) or die "Can't dup \$olderr: $!";

print "Restored!\n";
print $buffer;
```

Expected result:

```
Restored!
1: Test
Mo 25. Mär 13:44:53 CET 2019
2: Test
```

Actual result:

```
Restored!
1: Test
2: Test
```

Comment: Maybe `open3` cannot handle string buffer handles? Why not just use regular file handles for the `open3` call?

Comment: Using `eval` I can get the error message of the run3 statement:

`Error: run3(): Invalid argument redirecting STDOUT at /root/test_io.pl line 25.`

This doesn't help me though. Without reassigning `STDOUT` and `STDERR` the code works as expected. I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I try to avoid that because I don't want hundreds of temporary files.

Comment: Can you clarify/confirm for me -- do you want to, simply put, redirect stdout and stderr (separately), both for prints from the program and from external commands?  Just that, to redirect the streams?  That's done fairly simply, in a few ways. (Must it be a buffer (variable) and not a file?)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a solution to offer you, however I can provide some explanations as to the behavior you are seeing.

First, `IPC::Open3` is not supposed to work when your filehandles are variables; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045197/stdout-redirected-to-variable-not-catching-pipe-output) for more explanations.

Now, why isn't `IPC::Run3` working? First, notice that if don't redirect `STDERR` and run

```
run3 ["date"], undef, \$buffer, { append_stdout => 1 };
```

instead of

```
run3 ["date"], undef, \*STDOUT;
```

then it works as expected. (you need to add `{ append_stdout => 1 }` or your previous outputs to `$buffer` will be overwritten)

To understand what's happening, in your program, after

```
open(STDOUT, '>', \$buffer) or die "Can't redirect STDOUT: $!";
```

Add

```
print STDERR ref(\$buffer), "\n"
print STDERR ref(\*STDOUT), "\n"
```

Which will print

```
SCALAR
GLOB
```

That's exactly what `IPC::Run3::run3` will do to know what to do with the "stdout" you give it (see the source: [`_fh_for_child_output`](https://metacpan.org/release/IPC-Run3/source/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#L182), which is called by [`run3`](https://metacpan.org/release/IPC-Run3/source/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#L354)):

- if it's a scalar, then a temporary file is used (the corresponding line is [`$fh = $fh_cache{$what} ||= tempfile`](https://metacpan.org/release/IPC-Run3/source/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#L208), where `tempfile` is a function from [`File::Temp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html#*tempfile*).
- On the other hand, when stdout is a `GLOB` (or tied to `IO::Handle`), that filehandle is used directly (that's this [line of code](https://metacpan.org/release/IPC-Run3/source/lib/IPC/Run3.pm#L195)).

Which explains why when you call `run3` with `\$buffer` it works, but not with `\*STDOUT`.

---

When redirecting `STDERR` as well, and calling

```
run3 ["date"], undef, \$buffer, \$buffer, { append_stdout => 1, append_stderr => 1 };
```

, things start to appear weird. I don't understand what's happening, but I'll share here what I found, and hopefully someone will make sense of it.

I modified the source of `IPC::Run3` and added

```
open my $FP, '>', 'logs.txt' or die "Can't open: $!";
```

at the beginning of the sub `run3`. When running, I only see

```
Restored!
1: Test
```

on STDOUT (my terminal), but `logs.txt` contains the date (something in the lines of `Mon Mar 25 17:49:44 CET 2019`).

Investing a bit reveals that `fileno $FP` returns `1` (which, unless I mistaken, is usually `STDOUT` (but you closed it, so I'm no so surprised that its descriptor can be reused)), and `fileno STDOUT` returns `2` (this might depend on your Perl version and other opened filehandles though). What *seems* to be happening is that `system` assumes that `STDOUT` is the file descriptor `1` and thus prints to `$FP` instead of `STDOUT` (I'm just guessing though).

Please feel free to comment/edit if you understand what's happening.

Comment: To anyone who knows better than me: should this behavior of `IPC::Run3` be considered a bug?

Comment: Sadly this solution does not appear to have the desired effect. As long as I don't actually redirect STDOUT and STDERR and only redirect the output of `run3` this works fine. As soon as I do however the call fails:

run3(): Bad file descriptor restoring STDOUT, run3(): Bad file descriptor restoring STDERR at ./testio2.pl line 22

Comment: @K.A.B. Indeed, my bad, I have a good idea of why this is happening; I'm trying to fix it right now.

Comment: This is not a bug, you must pass filehandles to IPC::Open3.

Comment: @Dada That is IPC::Run3. It is completely unrelated.

Comment: @Grinnz oh, sorry, I thought you were talking about IPC::Run3, not IPC::Open3, my bad. But my question about whether this is a bug was related to IPC::Run3, not IPC::Open3 ;-)

Comment: @Dada It is common that closing STDOUT/STDERR causes problems like this so that's a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: The page with the question you link to _also shows a way for that to work_ (in the other answer), using `IPC::Run3` (clearly acceptable here).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CSDAL
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Run3;
use IO::Scalar;
use Encode;
use utf8;

# Save old filehandles
open(my $oldout, ">&STDOUT") or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";
open(my $olderr, ">&STDERR") or die "Can't dup STDERR: $!";

open(my $FH, "+>>:utf8", undef) or die $!;
$FH->autoflush;

close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);

open(STDOUT, '>&', $FH) or die "Can't redirect STDOUT: $!";
open(STDERR, '>&', $FH) or die "Can't redirect STDOUT: $!";

print "1: Test\n";

run3 ["/bin/date"], undef, $FH, $FH, { append_stdout => 1, append_stderr => 1 };

print STDERR "2: Test\n";

open(STDOUT, ">&", $oldout) or die "Can't dup \$oldout: $!";
open(STDERR, ">&", $olderr) or die "Can't dup \$olderr: $!";

print "Restored!\n";
seek($FH, 0, 0);
while(<$FH>)
{
  # No idea why this is even required
  print Encode::decode_utf8($_);
}
close($FH);
```

This is far from what I originally wanted, but appears to be working at least.

The issues I have with this are:

1. I need an anonymous file handle creating clutter on the hard disk.
2. For some reason I need to fix the encoding manually.

Thank you very much to the people who dedicated their time helping me out here.

Comment: Adding `binmode_stdin => ":utf8", binmode_stdout => ":utf8", binmode_stderr => ":utf8"` to the run3 options fixed my enconding issues thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use the parent's STDOUT and STDERR? IPC::Open3 is easily capable of redirecting the child's STDOUT and STDERR to unrelated handles in the parent which you can read from.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;

my $pid = open3 undef, my $outerr, undef, 'date';
my $output = do { local $/; readline $outerr };
waitpid $pid, 0;
my $exit = $? >> 8;
```

This will read STDOUT and STDERR together, if you want to read them separately you need to pass `my $stderr = Symbol::gensym` as the third argument (as shown in the IPC::Open3 docs), and use a non-blocking loop to avoid deadlocking when reading both handles. [IO::Async::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Process) or similar can fully automate this for you, but IPC::Run3 provides a much simpler solution if you only need to store the output in scalar variables. IPC::Run3 and Capture::Tiny can also both easily be [fatpacked](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) for deployment in scripts.

Comment: Note that using lexical handles for STDIN had a problem before 5.14  `perl -MIPC::Open3 -we'open(my $fh, "<", "/dev/null") or die $!;  open3("<&".fileno($fh), ">&STDOUT", ">&STDERR", "cat")'` threw `open3: close(3) failed: Bad file descriptor at -e line 1` before that.

Comment: @ikegami That syntax is duping handles, which also won't work with handles opened in-memory since they have no fd - my example isn't referring to that, but passing lexical handles to use directly.

Comment: You post suggests that lexicals are just as good as globs when dealing with IPC::Open2/3, but that wasn't the case before 5.14. That's it. Just a comment in case it matters to someone. I'm not saying your post should be edited.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer yet, but it seems like `open3` requires `STDOUT` to be a regular tty file handle at the time you call `open3`, for example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';
{
    local *STDOUT;  # <-- if you comment out this line open3 works as expected
    my ($chld_in, $chld_out);
    my $chld_err = gensym;
    my $pid;
    eval {
        $pid = open3($chld_in, $chld_out, $chld_err, "date");
    };
    if ( $@ ) {
        say "IPC::Open::open3 failed: '$@'";
    }
    print "-> $_" for <$chld_out>;
    waitpid $pid, 0;
   # say "Cannot print to invalid handle..";
}
say "ok";
```

**Output**:

```
ma. 25. mars 16:00:01 +0100 2019
ok
```

Note that the arrow `->` in the beginning of the line is missing, 
so nothing can be read from `$chld_out` in this case. However, if I comment out the line:

```
local *STDOUT;
```

The output is:

```
-> ma. 25. mars 16:01:10 +0100 2019
ok
```

Comment: This code suffers from a race condition. If the child sends a sufficient amount to its STDERR, both the child and parent will block forever.

Comment: @ikegami Good catch. I guess you mean one should implement a `select` loop to check whether STDOUT *or* STDERR is ready to reading? And then read from the handle which is ready

Comment: It would be much better to use something like [IO::Async::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Process) to go down that road, but IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run are much simpler if they do what you need.