# Open a scalar as a file in Perl

Tags: perl

According to PerlDoc you can direct a file open to a scalar variable https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Opening-a-filehandle-into-an-in-memory-scalar

I am trying to establish if I can use this approach for a temp file that is persistent within the lexical domain. I am doing the following as a test:

```
my $memfile;
my $filename=\$memfile;

open (OUT, ">", $filename);
print OUT "some data\n";
close (OUT);
```

I want to be able to read from the scalar later; eg:

```
open (IN, "<", $filename);
while (my $in=<IN>)
{
  print "$in\n";
}
close (IN);
```

This doesn't work, so am I barking mad or is there a right way to do it so it does work?

Comment: `perl -wE'open my $fh, ">", \my $mem or die $!; say $fh "hi"; say "var: $mem"'` works fine

Comment: Or, if you insist on another layer of variables (why that?), `perl -wE'my $mem; my $f = \$mem; open my $fh, ">", $f or die $!; say $fh "hi"; say "var: $mem"'`  works as well

Comment: I made a typo on my actual test code and now I fixe dit, it works. I feel so dumb now.

Comment: "_typo on my actual test code_" -- ok, no dumb, happens all the time to everybody :)

Comment: "_use this approach for a temp file that is persistent within the lexical domain._"  --- btw, what do you mean by "_persistent_" and by "_lexical domain_"?  That the file itself exists while in the scope and is gone once that scope is left?  Perhaps look into `File::Temp`?

Comment: Also [asked in /r/perl](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/10jn0hb/using_a_scalar_as_a_file_in_perl5/). It's fine to crosspost but tell people you are doing that so they don't spend time answering a question that already has an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can indeed open a filehandle to a variable, and write to it; and then we can use it like any other variable

```
open my $fhv, '>', \my $memfile or die $!;
say $fhv "hi";
close $fhv;

print $memfile;  # hi\n
```

One *can* also open a filehandle to the variable's reference for reading, like in the question, but this usually isn't needed. (A possible use would be if we want to keep writing *and* reading such that it can be changed between file/variable merely by changing the `open` statement.)

This works with another "layer" of variables, like in the question, as well,

```
 my $memfile;
 my $file = \$memfile;
 open my $fhv, '>', $file or die $!;
 say $fhv "hi";
 close $fhv;

 print $memfile;
```

Can again open a filehandle to `$file` for reading, as well.

Note that `$fhv` isn't quite a proper filehandle and some filehandle-uses will not work; see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47045197/4653379) for one example.

Comment: It turns out I made a typo in my test code and of course it works when I fixed it. I feel so dumb right now.

Comment: Alright, it happens :).  Btw, if you need more advanced and flexible (etc) ways to read/write from/to resources try out `IPC::Run`.  It supports all kinds of things

Comment: @quentinnuk Edited a little; nothing dramatic but you may want to take a glance